# How would I copy specific columns from a row to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Basically I'm compiling a report and can copy each row over in the correct order to another sheet, but I don't need every column of each row. I only need 3 out of 42 columns in each row to transfer over to the new sheet. Here's my code so far:

```
For k = 2 To coor2(2)
 If Cells(k, 5).Value > Cells(k, 16).Value Then
 Cells(k, 5).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("test").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
 End If
Next k
```

Comment: So you've got code... your question (title) doesn't make much sense when comparing the two.  Do you want a row copied, based on a couple cell values, a few select cells form the row, or do you want a contiguous range of cells copied?  Rows(k).Copy for the prior, individual statements for the middle, or you need to specify source and destination ranges for the latter.

Comment: Ignore the If statement, that part is fine. What I need help on is figuring out how to copy specific cells within that row instead of the EntireRow.

Answer (score 0):

```
For k = 2 To coor2(2)
 If Cells(k, 5).Value > Cells(k, 16).Value Then 
     With Sheets("test").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
         Cells(k, 5).Copy .Offset(1, 0)
         Cells(k, 7).Copy .Offset(1, 1)
         Cells(k, 9).Copy .Offset(1, 2)
     End With
 End If
Next k
```

Answer (score 0):

Tim pretty much has the gist of copying individual cells... will list all 3 variations as listed in my comment.

1) For an entire row:

```
Sheets("Source").Rows(k).Copy Sheets("Destination").Rows(lastrow+1)
```

2) For a specific cell (or non-contiguous ranges)

```
Sheets("Source").Cells(k,3).Copy Sheets("Destination").Cells(lastrow+1,1)
Sheets("Source").Cells(k,5).Copy Sheets("Destination").Cells(lastrow+1,2)
Sheets("Source").Cells(k,7).Copy Sheets("Destination").Cells(lastrow+1,3)
```

3) For a contiguous range

```
Sheets("Source").Range(Sheets("Source").Cells(k,3),Sheets("Source").Cells(k,7)).Copy Sheets("Destination").Range(Sheets("Destination").Cells(k,1),Sheets("Destination").Cells(k,5))
```

In each scenario, it is assumed you previously found the last row of the destination sheet and are pasting into the row AFTER last row.